# Tinymce applies heading style to whole paragraph, not only selected text

Tags: tinymce

I have just noticed an annoying behavior of TinyMCE editor. When I have written, let's say, a few paragraphs of text, and I want to select some of it and make it a heading (Heading 2 style), the whole text gets that heading style, not only the text I have selected.

This is not happening when I want to apply bolding - in this case it works as expected; only the selected text becomes bolded.

**How can I change this behavior?** I know there is HTML mode where I can change the style, but I am afraid my clients are not so familiar with HTML and they'd want to use visual mode only.

Comment: You'll have to move the text of a header into it's own paragraph before hitting the header styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the native behavior of TinyMCE and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is because h2-tags usually are not valid as child nodes of paragraphs.
You may try to adjust the tinymce configuration parameter [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround that I've found. Works great for me

```
tinyMCE.PluginManager.add('FormatingToolbarButtons', function (editor, url) {
['pre', 'p', 'code', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'].forEach(function (name) {
    editor.addButton("style-" + name, {
        tooltip: "Toggle " + name,
        text: name.toUpperCase(),
        onClick: function () {
            if (this.active()) {
                editor.execCommand('mceToggleFormat', false, name);
                this.active(false)
            }
            else {
                editor.selection.setContent('<' + name + '>' + editor.selection.getContent() + '</' + name + '>');
                this.active(true)
            }
        },
        onPostRender: function () {
            var self = this, setup = function () {
                editor.formatter.formatChanged(name, function (state) {
                    self.active(state);
                });
            };
            editor.formatter ? setup() : editor.on('init', setup);
        }
    })
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@force_br_newlines/

Try `force_p_newlines : true,` and see if it works.